# How do I add tags/taxonomy to images + a query field on page to query 'albums' (images with same tag/taxonomy)

Tags: taxonomy, query, tags, gallery

I've got lots and lots of photos on my site and I want to seperate them into albums. Every album is a client album (photoshoot).

Though.. I want all my clients to query their album on my site. Something like:
*Go to site, page "View your album!", fill in a search bar with unique id (e.g. Client.001.2013) and click non 'Show'. Now they see all their photos (that share the same id, (e.g. Client.001.2013).

So summarized: I need two things (I guess), a way to give all my photos an ID/tag/Taxonomy (back-end) and a search bar on the front end of the site, so people can query those ID's/Tags/Taxonomies, so they see all pictures who share the same ID.

What can you people advise me?

++ for thosesuggestions of a plugin that automatically nicely shows all the queried images in a gallery order or such.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can search google for WordPress plugins.

check these may be work for you

1. [Photosmash Galleries](http://wordpress.org/plugins/photosmash-galleries/screenshots/)
2. [WP Photo Album Plus](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-photo-album-plus/)